# How to troubleshoot simple injector in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

I'm using the Simple Injector IoC container in my web api service. Currently, I'm experiencing an error that I'm finding very difficult to investigate.

The container is configured as follows:

```
var container = new Container();

container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();

container.Register<IQueryHandler<LoginQuery, AccountDTO>, LoginQueryHandler>(
    Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

When requests come into the web service, rather than being routed to controllers, they are instead handled by a custom message handler. These handlers are created by inheriting from the `DelegatingHandler` class (see [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers) for more info).

The custom message handler will then look at the request and invoke a specific handler to handle the request. This is done as follows:

```
// For the sake of the example (and my testing), I have hard coded the types
// below, but usually these are pulled from the request.
Type handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)
    .MakeGenericType(typeof(AccountQuery), typeof(AccountDTO));

try
{
    // Something does wrong here
    dynamic handler = this.handlerFactory.Invoke(handlerType);

    // Code execution never reaches this point, exception is not caught
    ... other code
}
// I have also just tried catching the general exception
catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
{
    // do something
}
```

My current problem is that something goes wrong when trying to invoke the handler from the handler factory (simple injector). When I'm debugging, as soon as I step through that line, I imagine the web service hits an exception, and returns (my client just gets an "Internal Server Error" message). Despite the try/catch, no exceptions are caught, so I have absolutely no idea what is happening. I would think I probably have something configured wrong for simple injector, but I just don't know what (simple injector verifies successfully).

Does anyone have suggestions on what I can do here to figure out what is going on?

Comment: have you tried to check the `Network` request in google chrome ? i think error  must be shown there

Comment: May be you can use `PostMan` for sending request for test. it will show you little bit more details not just "Internal Server Error".

Comment: This problem seems completely unrelated to Simple Injector. Your Visual Studio debugger doesn't break on exceptions. You probably have to change its settings.

Comment: Yup @Steven you'd be correct. I had no idea you could have so much control over what exceptions get caught (everything was set to defaults). So, now I'm getting a useful exception message. `The IQueryHandler<AccountQuery, AccountDTO> is registered as 'Web API Request' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of a Web API Request.` I thought the message handlers would be in the context - so, when does a web api context actually start? Is the solution to use: `using (container.BeginExecutionContextScope()) { }` ?

Comment: @Steven I've noticed that in your [SolidServices](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/solidservices) example that you don't register things as `Scoped` nor do you use `container.BeginExecutionContextScope()`. After a request is handled by the web service, are you just relying on the GC to clean things up?

Comment: @Andrew: You should read [this](https://simpleinjector.org/webapi). You need to register the `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver`. The SOLIDServices project lacks this registration, because there are no scoped registrations.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Steven. I was also missing `request.GetDependencyScope();` in my message handler, which triggers the scope. If anyone is looking for more details, this is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html#injecting-dependencies-into-web-api-message-handlers)